# Android 13 crash: Getting securityException (calling identity is not authorized) crash on android 13

Tags: android, crash, securityexception, android-securityexception, android-13

facebookincubator/Battery-Metrics repo's getSnapshot method in class SystemMetricsCollector is crashing because of **java.lang.SecurityException: Calling identity is not authorized** on android 13. It was working on android 12 and on versions before. Logs for the crash are:

`java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{AppName/com.AppName.ux.activity.MainActivity}: java.lang.SecurityException: Calling identity is not authorized at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3686) at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3823) at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135) at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95) at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2306) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7892) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:548) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:936) Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Calling identity is not authorized at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:3011) at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2995) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2978) at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2920) at android.net.INetworkStatsService$Stub$Proxy.openSessionForUsageStats(INetworkStatsService.java:469) at android.app.usage.NetworkStats.<init>(NetworkStats.java:111) at android.app.usage.NetworkStatsManager.querySummary(NetworkStatsManager.java:424) at android.app.usage.NetworkStatsManager.querySummary(NetworkStatsManager.java:397) at com.facebook.battery.metrics.network.NetworkStatsManagerBytesCollector.getBytesForType(NetworkStatsManagerBytesCollector.java:51) at com.facebook.battery.metrics.network.NetworkStatsManagerBytesCollector.getTotalBytes(NetworkStatsManagerBytesCollector.java:38) at com.facebook.battery.metrics.network.NetworkMetricsCollector.getSnapshot(NetworkMetricsCollector.java:53) at com.facebook.battery.metrics.network.NetworkMetricsCollector.getSnapshot(NetworkMetricsCollector.java:33) at com.facebook.battery.metrics.composite.CompositeMetricsCollector.getSnapshot(CompositeMetricsCollector.java:99) at com.AppName.features.appsetup.ux.workflow.tasks.LaunchScreenTask.process(LaunchScreenTask.java:66) at com.AppName.features.appsetup.ux.workflow.WorkflowExecutor.execute(WorkflowExecutor.java:84) at com.AppName.ux.activity.MainActivity.startWorkflow(MainActivity.java:414) at com.AppName.ux.activity.MainActivity.workflowDelegation(MainActivity.java:1134) at com.AppName.ux.activity.MainActivity.ecsEventHandler(MainActivity.java:568) at com.AppName.ux.activity.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:324) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8285) at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8264) at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1384) at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3667)`

Comment: I'm getting the same exception with MSDefender on first time setup in Android 13, looks like there's some breaking change in Android platform

Comment: Were you able to fix it ? I'm getting the same issue when using `DevicePolicyManager#setRequiredStrongAuthTimeout`